# Looking into double timeseries arrays in structs

Tags: matlab, time-series, workspace

In my matlab-workspace i have a `struct` that's including a lot of `double timeseries`. Sometimes I can just open those timeseries and matlab will show me an array with 2 columns and a large amount of rows. But then sometimes I can not actually look into the double time series, but can only see this, when i double click it:

> timeseries
>
> Common Properties:
>               Name: 'M_s_Nm'
>               Time: [150649x1 double]
>           TimeInfo: tsdata.timemetadata
>               Data: [1x1x150649 double]
>           DataInfo: tsdata.datametadata

Both can be useful from time to time and I would like to be able, which I'm going to get shown.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem here? If your structure field contains an `Nx2` array it will show it as such, but is it contains other things it can't show it as an array. The example you posted contains an `Nx1` array and an `1x1xN` array amongst others, both not `Nx2`

Comment: but in fact i can see them sometimes, and sometimes i can't...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because the size of `Time` and `Data` is too large to be shown in the Variable window (Time: [150649x1 double]). Try read it chunk by chunk, for example:

```
timeser = structname.fieldname;
t = timeser.Time(1:100);
```

You can now read `t` in the Variables window if you wish.

Comment: Yes, I can see them this way of course, but that's not the intention of the question. I have to look at those data-structs quite often and i don't always want to do that via the command window. especially because i would also have to use `find` to check which time-index is for which actual time data and it would slow my work down pretty much